# Batch script - copy file into all subfolders

Tags: windows-10, batch

Here is my directory structure:
[image]

I am simply looking for a batch script that will copy "srt.bat" to all the folders in the same directory.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Example script (You must have enabled command extensions)

```
FOR /D %d IN (*) DO COPY srt.bat %d
```

In the batch file cp.bat it looks like:

```
for /D %%d in (*) do copy srt.bat %%d
```

Please remember that names of variables are case sensitive

---

After comments below:

At last I modified cp.bat like below (to use parameter in call the batch file)

```
for /D %%d in (*) do copy %1 %%d
```

and created another script main.bat:

```
cp.bat srt.bat
```

It works

Comment: It throws an error  "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Comment: Please respond to agon024.

Comment: @agon024 Try using double quotes in the `COPY` portion of the command e.g. `COPY srt.bat "%D"`. As a side note, if you are running this command from another batch file (rather than the command line), you should also double the percent signs (i.e. use `%%D` rather than just `%D`)

Comment: @agon024 - please check if the command extension are enabled. I gave you "fast-checked" solution. wihout describing all circumstances. And yes - if you embed this in another batch, you have to add addtional percent prefix before variable name.

Comment: Folks, this is not  running in another batch file, I would have said that in the original post. The first thing said in the response was to make sure that "command extensions" are enabled. In regedit under "Command Processor", EnableExtensions is set to "1". I made sure from the start. Adding quotes around %D in the copy portion did not work either.

Comment: @Anaksunaman, adding quotes didn't work and this is not running inside of another batch script.

Comment: That is exactly copy-paste from my batch script:
for /d %%d in (*) do copy test2.txt %%d 
In my test file copied is named test2.txt and is copied to three different directories. Version presented in cmd.exe window is Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.804] I run cp.bat inside cmd.exe window

Comment: I didn't test it from another batch file - there was not in the question. How do you call it?